# How to read type definitions in Elm

Tags: types, syntax, elm

How should I read a type definition like the following?

```
type Config data msg =
  Config
    { toId : data -> String
    , toMsg : State -> msg
    , columns : List (ColumnData data msg)
    , customizations : Customizations data msg
    }
```

There seems to be a "repeating" element to it: **Config** is present on the LHS and the RHS.

Another example is this:

```
type State =
  State String Bool
```

What are these type declarations communicating?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The left-hand side names the type you will be creating. On the right hand side, you will define the values the type can actually take. There can be just one or however much you want.

```
type MyType = ValueA | ValueB | ValueC
```

Additionally, you can make types whose values contain extra data. That can be done by following the value name (formally called *data constructor*, or *variant* in Elm) by another type. You can use any concrete type and have any number of them. The types and arities (numbers of arguments) do not need to be the same between variants.

```
type MyType = ValueA String | ValueB Int (List String) | ValueC
```

These have all been concrete types. When you have a value, it will always have a concrete type. Suppose you want to create your own pair type. You could define

```
type PairOfIntAndInt = PairOfIntAndInt Int Int
type PairOfIntAndString = PairOfIntAndString Int String
type PairOfStringAndString = PairOfStringAndString String String
…
```

but that would not be very convenient. For that reason, Elm allows you to have *type constructors* (that is the formal name of the type name on the LHS) with parameters. They will be written in lowercase letters:

```
type Pair first second = Pair first second
```

Many useful core features like `Maybe` or `Result` in fact are types that accept parameters. They are also called abstract types. To make them a concrete type, you need to pass them a concrete type [^1] to each parameter.

Now, let’s look at your code. You have a type constructor `Config` that takes two parameters.

```
type Config data msg =
```

And the type accepts values created with its one data constructor

```
  Config
```

which stores a single value. The type of the value is actually a composed type, a record. It expects four fields and their types will depend on the parameters of the type constructor.

```
    { toId : data -> String
    , toMsg : State -> msg
    , columns : List (ColumnData data msg)
    , customizations : Customizations data msg
    }
```

For example, if you have a concrete type `Config String Int`, it will expect the following value:

```
Config
  { toId = someToIdValue
  , toMsg = someToMsgValue
  , columns = someColumnsValue
  , customizations = someCustomizationsValue
}
```

where `someToIdValue` will have to be a function taking `String` and returning `String`, `toMsg` a function from `State` to `Int`, and so on.

For more information, see https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/custom_types.html

[^1]: Some languages like Haskell actually allow wilder types. https://wiki.haskell.org/Kind

Comment: Data constructors are called variants in Elm, btw. I'm also pretty sure that parameterized type constructors aren't called abstract types. Abstract in regards to types usually mean the implementation is hidden, and the ability to do so with custom types is, I think, the only reason to use a single constructor custom type instead of  an alias.

Comment: Thanks, I have switched to variant term. Albeit it is not clear to me if it refers to the data constructor, or the whole summand.

I have [seen](https://wiki.haskell.org/Abstract_data_type#Tree) the term abstract used for this kind of thing, though it is not the only case where type is considered abstract – and the term already has many uses, including the ADT term. Perhaps some counterpart to *inhabited type* would be a better term but I am not aware of any.

Comment: Interesting. I think the more widely used, and IMO less confusing term for this is "generic", as opposed to "concrete".

Comment: I think generic refers to types with *non-nullary type constructors* in OOP languages. In that parlance, concrete types would be (fully) specialized generic types.

Comment: Is there really a difference? Other than in culture or perspective? Either way, as I said earlier, I think the purpose of both `State` and `Config` here is to make the types abstract by not exporting the data constructors, which is a different meaning from the way you use the term in your answer. Even if technically correct, I find it very confusing. Could either term perhaps be qualified in some way to disambiguate them?